How can I assign a heredoc to a variable in a way that's portable across Unix and Mac?
This code works fine on Linux but not Mac OS:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo=$(cat <<EOF
"\[^"\]+"
EOF
)
printf "%s" "$foo"

It fails on Mac with
./test.sh: line 6: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
./test.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

If I do cat <<EOF instead of foo=$(cat <<EOF, it works fine.  Is there a portable way to get heredocs (or multiline strings) into variables without using a file as an intermediate?
Edit: I want to use a heredoc becuase I have a multiline string with " and '.  My actual example looks like:
EXPECTED_ERROR=$(cat <<EOF
Set
     : Type
File "/tmp/tmp[A-Za-z0-9_/]\+\.v", line 1\(0\|1\), characters 0-15:
Error: The command has not failed\s\?!

.\?Does this output display the correct error? \[(y)es/(n)o\]\s
I think the error is 'Error: The command has not failed\s\?!
.\?'\.
The corresponding regular expression is 'File "\[^"\]+", line (\[0-9\]+), characters \[0-9-\]+:\\\\n(Error:\\\\s+The\\\\s+command\\\\s+has\\\\s+not\\\\s+failed.*
EOF
)


(1) What is bash --version in each case? (2) What do you mean by "portable" here? Do you mean "following POSIX" or "working even in presence of bugs that have been fixed in newer versions"? There was a bug which may be relevant here.

@KamilMaciorowski, it can't have been that fix as that bug was already fixed in 4.0.

On Mac OSX, I see % bash --version GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23) Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc..

FWIW, this seems to work in zsh, even if it doesn't work in bash.

Nuclear option: #!/usr/local/bin/bash

That particular bash bug was fixed in 4.0, released over 15 years ago, but macos still ships a 3.2.x version. Since Apple will apparently not upgrade their bash (and their sh which AFAIK is still based on bash), I'd suggest you report the bug to them so they backport a fix to their version.
It seems it affects here-documents used inside command substitution, so you could move the here-doc out of the command substitution with:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
{
  foo=$(cat)
} <<'EOF'
"\[^"\]+"
EOF
printf %s "$foo"

or by using a helper function:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
helper() {
  cat <<'EOF'
"\[^"\]+"
EOF
}
foo=$(helper)
printf %s "$foo"

Or a more useful one:
#! /usr/bin/env bash
readvar() {
  eval "$1=\$(cat)"
}
readvar foo << 'EOF'
"\[^"\]+"
EOF
printf %s "$foo"

(above also using 'EOF' instead of EOF as the latter does expansions and implies extra handling of backslash).
Or delay the here-doc interpretation by using eval:
#!/usr/bin/env bash
foo=$(eval 'cat <<EOF
"\[^"\]+"
EOF')
printf %s "$foo"

Though I suspect that you're using here-docs in the first place to avoid having to worry about quote nesting so that eval '...' will likely not help.
A note on terminology:

Mac refers to a line of computer hardware by Apple of different architectures (some of which PC-based) which can run a variety of Unix-like or non-Unix-like operating systems, though come pre-installed with Apple macos (formerly knows as OS/X, MacOS/X). So is hardly relevant.
Unix is a family of operating systems dating back to the original Unix OS developed at Bell labs in the 70s to which macos and most generic GNU/Linux based operating systems belong.
Linux is the kernel found at the core of thousands of different operating systems some (most) of which Unix-like, some not.
bash is the shell of the GNU project, it's mostly a free and opensource part-clone of the Korn shell (which itself was closed source until around 2000), first released in 1989 (so predates both Linux and MacOS/X) and can be built for most if not all Unix-like systems and several non-Unix-like ones. It is preinstalled on GNU systems, several non-GNU Linux-based systems, and some non-GNU non-Linux systems such as macos, though there, it's a very ancient pre-GPL3 version.

Here, the issue is solely about the version of bash, you'd hit the same bug in any system from before 2009 and that had bash included.

A non-command-substitution approach that works in the oldest bashes I have (not reaching 3.2):
$ read -r -d '' VAR <<'EOF'
multiline data that can include
all kind " ' of quotes or anything 
including \ backslash or $dollar
EOF
$


That should be IFS= read -rd '' var to prevent stripping leading and trailing whitespace (or other characters depending on the current value of $IFS), but then the trailing newlines (which command substitution strips) would be kept. Beware it also returns a failure exit status (as the NUL delimiter is not found; bash doesn't support embedding NULs in its here docs anyway).

Providing this as an answer here to provide completeness, as the answers all contain the correct answers. This just adds another "correct" option for the OP.
A Bit of History
Darwin, based on BSD, and the core of MacOS was free and OpenSource until Darwin8.  Darwin8 is still available and will give you a very basic OSX 10.4.  There will be no GUI in that install.  After Darwin8, Apple chose to make the OS closed-source.  It's also this Darwin8 that contains the last GPL'ed version of Apple's BASH - 3.2.x, which is why no user will ever see a native Apple BASH version higher than 3.2.x
Apple used the graphical objects from NeXTStep, and Darwin8 above to form the basis of all modern OSX's since 10.4 and the source code remains closed-source with bits and pieces shared at Apple's Developer website.  Darwin, without the attached Apple can still be used, and seen today in projects like PureDarwin.  Note that there is still no native NeXTStep type GUI here or any native GUI, but the system will run desktops like XFCE using MacPorts. Homebrew, discussed below, is a package manger that is mostly used to replace the Apple/Darwin versions of programs and libraries wit their Linux counterparts (without removing the Apple supplied versions). MacPorts works much the same but contains not only Linux binaries but graphical applications as well.
The Issue
With the small history out of the way, Multiple Sites center around the fact that Apple would violate the GPLv2 license if BASH were updated past the version in Darwin8.  Reporting the bug, may do no good as the fix would need to be backported to continue avoiding violation. If the fix was included in BASH4 as Stephane's answer has stated, Apple now has put themselves in a catch-22/chicken and egg problem.  In order to upgrade BASH to a version greater than 3.2, all the source code (including the closed source NeXTStep code) would need to be re-released, which would satisfy the GPLv2 license. Apple doesn't want the public seeing that code. See Sarcasm below for my personal opinion as to why.

Begin Sarcasm
BTW, I put this here, and I own a Macbook Pro (last generation Intel), so even I fell for the
nice GUI and shiny color. I also own a gaming tower, a cheap Toshiba
Satellite, a Raspberry Pi4, an iPad, and an Android based phone, so please keep the Apple fanboy
comments out of the comment section.
Let's face it, half (if not
more) of the customers who buy a Mac buy it because the outside is
shiny and the GUI is intuitive and nicely designed. In other words, the
"simplistic beauty" of the GUI, and the shiny case colors are part of
the reason buying a Mac is such a lucrative money making endeavor for
for Apple. As such, Apple will never reopen any source code.
A customer who uses shiny case colors and great looking GUI's to judge the worthiness of their computer isn't really going to care if their BASH version is 18 years out of date.
End Sarcasm

The top answer in the search result linked earlier contains the following:

Apple uses an ancient version of Bash 3.2.57 initially released in 2006, and due to GNU's GPL2/3 licensing, Apple will not install a more recent version of Bash (e.g. 5.2) that is installed on most Linux systems.  Instead, Apple is committed to providing the ZSH shell which has an MIT license. Learning the ZSH shell would be more strategic for you in future releases of macOS.

Committed to providing the ZSH Shell is just a fancy way of saying we have lots of lawyers who tell us violating the GPL would be bad so let's find a viable replacement with a license that isn't GPL.  ZSH happens to be that suitable replacement.
My Solution
Apple system users are OK saying just switch terminal interpreters, but as a user of both systems (PC and Mac), I've found that installing the Homebrew version of BASH fixes the design decision chosen by Apple.

Install Homebrew.
Use How to change bash versions on Mac with Homebrew, or similar to install an updated BASH version. Just search for Install or Update BASH on MacOS X

Doing this now makes BASH scripts between nearly all Linux distributions and a Mac compatible, and if desired provides users a way to continue using a BASH shell that they're used to.
Drawback
If users need portability (going from one Mac to another), and not compatibility, the above approach is discouraged.  In the portability case, we have 2 options:

Learn ZSH - Most hardcore Mac scripters take this approach and then do the opposite above and change the default shell in Linux to ZSH, which is a lot easier in Linux's case than adding new non-native BASH to Mac.
Don't do Anything, and learn the oddities like the OP discovered here and solve them one at a time, keeping a file for future reference.

Update Per Comments
Quoting The Top 10 Questions about the GPL License – Answered!


Can I sell GPL-licensed software?

Yes. However, the GPL requires that the source code be made available to anyone who receives a copy of the software. Customers who purchase GPL-licensed software have the right to access and modify the underlying source code.
When you sell GPL-licensed software, you are essentially selling a copy of the software along with the rights and freedoms granted by the GPL. The GPL allows you to charge a fee for distributing the software, but you must also provide the recipients with the corresponding source code and grant them the same rights and freedoms that you received under the GPL.



Is the GPL a secure license?

The GPL is generally considered a strong copyleft license that’s safe to use. If you plan to combine GPL-licensed software with proprietary code, be aware that the entire project might need to be released under the GPL, which may not align with your business objectives. Always seek legal advice to ensure compliance with the license requirements.
Remember that the GPL is a copyleft license, which means that any modifications or derivative works based on the GPL-licensed software must also be distributed under the GPL.

And lastly:


Do I have to release my source code if I use a GPL library in my project?

Yes. If you use a GPL library in a project that’s released, the GPL requires that you release the source code of your entire project. This is because the GPL considers the combination of the library and your code as a derived work, subject to the copyleft requirements of the license. If you’ve modified a program’s source code for personal or internal use, there’s no need to release its source code. However, if you make the modified program available to the public, you must also make the code public.


My Thoughts Related to Above

may also apply here, but the main issue IMO is the derivative works bits.  Because the GUI was a separate piece of software developed by Steve Jobs himself, and according to NeXT's WikiPedia Entry:


Apple merged with NeXT in 1997 as part of a $427 million deal, including 1.5 million shares of Apple stock. The deal appointed Steve Jobs, then the chairman and CEO of NeXT, to an advisory role at Apple; and OPENSTEP was combined with the classic Mac OS, to create Rhapsody and Mac OS X.

Let's just assume that the addition of OpenStep/NeXTStep in this case could on the off chance be considered a derivative work, combined with the rather high price tag of $427 million dollars that Apple decided to play it safe, and remove the need to release such a derivative work, by changing licenses all-together. In this above case, Questions 4 and 5 strongly apply, even with a might, and I'm sure Apple's very highly paid legal team saw even a might as an issue.  Once again, as per the Sarcasm section above, let's be real, and agree that Apple is in business to make money, and last I heard they make a lot of it.  This is again the opposite of the intention of question 4. It should be common sense that any profit driven company who sells items built with heavy doses of intellectual property would not give said property (schematics, plans, drawings, source code etc.) away for free as question 4 implies.  Commenters can knit-pick over which sections would be released etc. for ages and possibly downvote a thorough answer.  That's fine, but they're all missing the point which is that not releasing source code protects profits and intellectual property.  The amount of code released or whether certain parts are released is immaterial.

From what I have read about the Apple's problem with GPL v3 I understand it they just want to avoid the hassle of being obliged to provide the source code of the GPL v3 licensed parts. GPL v3 has no such requirements on other parts of the system.

As pabouk says, GPLv3 wouldn’t force Apple to release the entire operating system; as I understand it the main concern has to do with the patent provisions in GPLv3, not source code publication requirements (which already exist in GPLv2).

Some of the "many sites" so fuzzily referred to here also mention the anti-tivoization clauses, but I'm not sure how actual an issue that would actually be. But I also have a hard time seeing why upgrading Bash would require releasing source to other pieces of software.

None of your additions quoting the GPL are relevant to bash (which is not a library) or GPL3. Apple does publish the code of many of the software it uses and modifies in its OS including its ancient bash (which it has to as it's GPL2 licensed), and some it doesn't have to. Most companies see the benefits of contributing to core software they use and share with others so they can focus on the other parts they try to make a difference with. As a (techy) user, having access to source code is also invaluable. Why Apple won't use GPL3 I have no idea myself.
